# DFS Maze generation

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, maze

Currently with the following algorithm I'm trying to generate a maze:

```
// m_maze is a m_dim*m_dim matrix filled which '#' which means a wall and ' ' means a free cell
// const int dxdy[4][2] = { {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0} }; // {UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT}
void Maze::generate() {
std::queue<std::pair<int, int>>neighbours;
neighbours.emplace(0, 0);
m_maze[0][0] = ' '; // marking a free cell
while (!neighbours.empty()) {
    std::pair<int, int> currentCell = neighbours.front();

    for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
        const int newX = currentCell.first + 2*dxdy[d][0];
        const int newY = currentCell.second + 2*dxdy[d][1];

        if (newX >= 0 && newY >= 0 && newX <= m_dim && newY <= m_dim && m_maze[newX][newY] && m_maze[newX][newY] == '#') {
            m_maze[currentCell.first + dxdy[d][0]][currentCell.second + dxdy[d][1]] = ' ';
            m_maze[newX][newY] = ' ';
            neighbours.emplace(newX, newY);
        }
    }

    neighbours.pop();
}
}
```

The problem is that the output looks like this:

```
                         #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 ##########################
```

I was thinking that this problem comes from the instructions inside if() statement, but I am not sure. The way I tought those instructions is: I'm removing a wall and then mark the next cell as free. Any tips?

Comment: 1) why do you double the deltas? 2) shouldn't `newX <= m_dim && newY <= m_dim` really be `newX < m_dim && newY < m_dim`?

Answer (score 0):

Why your algorithm produces such regular results is that there is no randomness.
Think the algorithm's work step by step.

At Starting point (0,0) : maze becomes to

```
@__#####
_#######
_#######
########
########
########
```

where, '@' is current position, and "free space" is shown with '_'

Next,

```
___#####
_#######
@__#####
_#######
_#######
########
```

Then

```
___#####
_#######
___#####
_#######
@__#####
########
```

And at the next step, downside position of '@' is already '_', can be step to right only. So it becomes to

```
__@__###
_#######
___#####
_#######
___#####
########
```

Since all subsequent steps are the same, the result will be as follows.

```
_______#
_#######
_______#
_#######
_______#
########
```

The directions are different between this example and your result, but this depends on how the index of the array is used.

---

You are digging all possible direction from current position at same time.
Changing this to "digging only one direction, and select this direction with random" will cause maze like result.